# Can I change the value of a component from a separate button in Compose Multiplatform?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, reflections, jetbrains-compose

I am trying to make a desktop application that allows you to search through a number of predefined locations stored in Kotlin classes in a separate directory. To accomplish this, I've used the [reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) and [compose-jb](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/) libraries.

The problem I've run into is that I can't figure out how to update a Column of Boxes (located in another Box component) to change when I press the search button after entering tags that I want to search by.

My code is below (for the Main.kt file) that describes the entire desktop application.

```kotlin
val reflections = Reflections("io.github.mobomega.project.attractions")
var display = mutableSetOf<Attraction>()

fun main() = application {
    val stateVertical = rememberScrollState(0)
    val stateHorizontal = rememberScrollState(0)
    var state = Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .verticalScroll(stateVertical)
            .padding(end = 12.dp, bottom = 12.dp)
            .horizontalScroll(stateHorizontal)
    )
    Window(
        onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication,
        title = "Search",
        state = rememberWindowState(width = 2256.dp, height = 1504.dp)
    ) {
        val count = remember { mutableStateOf(1) }
        MaterialTheme {
            Column {
                val text = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
                OutlinedTextField(
                    value = text.value,
                    singleLine = true,
                    onValueChange = { text.value = it },
                    modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                )
                Row (modifier = Modifier.size(2256.dp, 50.dp), horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center) {
                    Button(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Top),
                        onClick = {
                            val tags = text.value.split(", ", ",")
                            for (tag in tags) {
                                search(tag.lowercase())
                                println("$display have tag $tag")
                            }
                            // Setting the new value of the Box
                            state = create(stateVertical, stateHorizontal)
                            // Creates error:
                            // "@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function"

                        }) {
                        Text("Search")
                    }
                    Button (modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Top),
                        onClick = {
                            display.clear()
                        }) {
                        Text("Reset")
                    }
                }
                Row (horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center) {
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                            .background(color = Color(red = 0xFF, green = 0xFF, blue = 0xFF))
                            .padding(10.dp)

                    ) {

                        state // Creating the state Box component in the Row

                        VerticalScrollbar(
                            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterEnd)
                                .fillMaxHeight(),
                            adapter = rememberScrollbarAdapter(stateVertical)
                        )
                        HorizontalScrollbar(
                            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomStart)
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .padding(end = 12.dp),
                            adapter = rememberScrollbarAdapter(stateHorizontal)
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun textBox(text: String = "Item") {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.height(32.dp)
            .width(400.dp)
            .background(color = Color(200, 0, 0, 20))
            .padding(start = 10.dp),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterStart
    ) {
        Text(text = text)
    }
}

@Composable
fun create(stateVertical: ScrollState, stateHorizontal: ScrollState) = Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .verticalScroll(stateVertical)
        .padding(end = 12.dp, bottom = 12.dp)
        .horizontalScroll(stateHorizontal)
    ) {
        Column {
            var x = 0
            for (attr in display) {
                x++
                textBox(attr.name)
                if (x < display.size) {
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(5.dp).align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally))
                }
            }
        }
}

fun search(text: String) {
    for (attr in reflections.getSubTypesOf(Attraction::class.java)) {
        val temp = attr.getConstructor().newInstance()
        println("${temp.name} has tags ${temp.tags}")
        if (temp.matches(text) && (temp !in display)) {
            display += temp
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to update the value of the Box that contains all of the items that match any of the search criteria, but I have run into a number of issues, such as the "onClick" function in which I set the new value of the "state" variable (storing all of the matching items) not being a Composable function, and therefore I can't change the value.

How would I accomplish changing the value of a Component such as a Box from another Component, such as a Button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Compose you can't create a view like you're doing with `state` variable. Result of your call is just `Unit`, and when you later call it you should see a warning "The expression is unused". The view is added at the tree hierarchy at the moment your variable is created.

To solve your problem you need to declare `display` as a mutable state - it's a new thing made especially for Compose, which allows triggering recomposition when this state changes:

```
val display by mutableStateOf<Attraction>(setOf())
```

And then update like this in your `search`:

```
val mutableDisplay = mutableSetOf<Attraction>()
// for 
// ...
mutableDisplay += temp
// ...
display = mutableDisplay
```

Note that you can't use mutable set inside your mutable state, as mutable state won't be able to track changes of this set.

To learn more about state in Compose I suggest you checking [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/mymWGMy9pYI) which explains the basic principles, and Compose [mental model](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model) for better understanding of how to work with it.